# Windows MIT Kerberos, error 1765328190, krb5_cc_set_flags

Tags: hive, kerberos, cloudera, mit-kerberos, krb5.ini

I got error with MIT Kerberos, during testing ODBC connection to the HIVE

```
Credentils cache permissions incorrect (Kerberos error -1765328190)
krb5_cc_set_flags failed
```

How do you solve this issue?

I made these steps:

- I reinstall kfw-4.1-amd64.msi, version 4.1 (64-bit, for windows)
- I reinstall ClouderaHiveODBC64.msi, version 2.5.25.1020 (64-bit, for windows)
- I opened ports 10000 for hive and 88 fork KDC server
- I copy krb5.conf to directory c:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5\krb5.ini
- I setup system variables KRB5_CONFIG=c:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5\krb5.ini and KRB5CCNAME=c:\test\krb5cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, you have to use dynamic cache for Kerberos (path must be different for each user), not static. Use this setting for system variable KRB5CCNAME:

```
KRB5CCNAME=%USERPROFILE%\krb5cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and I solved it in the following way:

KRB5CCNAME=C:\temp\krb5cache\TEMP

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).